# FFmpeg display dts during encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I have some videos that has corrupted packets in them, so when I use `ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -an b.mp4` I sometimes get

```
[mpegts @ 00000197fdafcdc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 21326250).
C:\Users\jj\Desktop\a.mp4: corrupt input packet in stream 0
frame=  725 fps=174 q=28.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:27.50 bitrate= 457.6kbits/s speed= 6.6x    
[mpegts @ 00000197fdafcdc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 21596250).
C:\Users\jj\Desktop\a.mp4: corrupt input packet in stream 0
[mpegts @ 00000197fdafcdc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 21866250).
C:\Users\jj\Desktop\a.mp4: corrupt input packet in stream 0
```

While I don't understand `dts` completely, I can use ffprobe to get the max `dts` value and use that as a way to know how far in is the encoding process. Is there a way to display the `dts` value in a non-corrupt packet'd video? Since I'm trying to remove duplicated frames, there's no way to find out how much more of the video is left and this is the only way I can think of.

Something like this:

```
frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.29 bitrate=   1.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=6.91x   dts = 5
frame=  154 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:06.54 bitrate= 320.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=  12x   dts = 10 
frame=  287 fps=274 q=28.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:11.81 bitrate= 532.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=11.3x   dts = 15 
frame=  440 fps=285 q=28.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:17.98 bitrate= 583.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=11.6x   dts = 20 
frame=  554 fps=271 q=28.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:22.40 bitrate= 655.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=10.9x   dts = 25 
frame=  689 fps=270 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:27.98 bitrate= 674.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=  11x   dts = 30
```

Comment: You can insert a showinfo filter before mpdecimate.

Comment: @Gyan I could see some use to this but using this filter takes away the encoding info with the time and file size. Is there a work around to this?

Comment: Then just add -report to the command. ffmpeg will write debug logs to a report file. mpdecimate will write a line per frame with its timestamp and drop decision.